# How can I organize my LinkedIn connections into different contact lists such as Facebook friend lists?

Tags: linkedin

On Facebook I use friend lists to organize my connections. How can I do the same in LinkedIn?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The equivalent of Facebook friend lists for LinkedIn are [tags](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1020):

> To add or remove a tag from the Contacts page:
>
> - Move your cursor over Network at the top of your homepage and select
>     Contacts.
> - Move your cursor over the contact in the list and click Tag
>     below the contact's information.
> - Check the box next to an existing tag
>     or click +Add new tag to create a new one. If you create a new one,
>     type in the name of your tag and click Save. To remove a tag, uncheck
>     the box next to it.
>
> The tag will be visible to you on the person's
>   contact information and on their profile. You can click the tag in
>   these areas to see all other profiles with the same tag. Only you will
>   see the tags you've created.
>
> Note: You can create up to 200 new and unique tags or delete old ones.

As of 2018-03-25, the LinkedIn tagging feature [is no longer available](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/72280). There does not appear to be a way to self-organize LinkedIn contacts within the system itself.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of 2018-03-25, the LinkedIn tagging feature is no longer available. There does not appear to be a way to self-organize LinkedIn contacts within the system itself.